# Oracle 11g XE slow query execution

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, query-optimization

I face a problem regarding a select query i have created. The query is the following:

```
SELECT --184.791
  C.MSISDN
FROM 
  CONTACTS_HISTORY C 
  INNER JOIN WAVECONTACTS_HISTORY WC 
    ON C.CONTACTSID = WC.CONTACTSID 
WHERE
  C.CAMPAIGNSID = 472;
```

The `C.CAMPAIGNSID`, `C.CONTACTSID` and `WC.CONTACTSID` columns are indexed and the `WC.CONTACTSID` is a foregin key to the `C.CONTACTSID`.

The `CONTACTS_HISTORY` table has 3.000.000 records and the `WAVECONTACTS_HISTORY` table 2.000.000 records.

When I include the join in the query the execution is too slow.

The execution plan from the SQLDeveloper has a total cost of 3.

I can not understand why the execution is too slow. Is this because of the limitation of the XE edition?

The Oracle DB is installed on my laptop Intel Core i3, 8GB RAM (but I am aware of the limitations of this edition to 1 CPU, 1 Gb RAM)

```
OPERATION           OBJECT_NAME                 OPTIONS        COST 
SELECT STATEMENT                                               3
 NESTED LOOPS
  NESTED LOOPS                                                 3
   TABLE ACCESS     WAVECONTACTS_HISTORY        FULL           2
   INDEX            IX_CONTACTS_HISTORY_CMPSID  RANGE SCAN     1
    Access Predicates
  TABLE ACCESS      CONTACTS_HISTORY            BY INDEX ROWID 1
   Filter Predicates
    WC.CONTACTSID=C.CONTACTSID
```

Comment: Please post the execution plan (as text, not an image). Does it say it's using the indexes? Are the statistics up to date? How slow is too slow?

Comment: ia have added the execution plan also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the costs are out of whack, especially this one:

```
TABLE ACCESS     WAVECONTACTS_HISTORY        FULL           2
```

That's a FULL TABLE SCAN of two million row table.

Most likely your statistics are stale.  Gather fresh stats on the tables and indexes, and you should see a much smarter and efficient execution plan. [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#ARPLS059)

That may not be the whole solution.  Tuning is dependent on a number of factors, such as skew and distribution.  For instance, if you have relatively few Campaigns in your Contact History and they're spread across the table the index on C.CAMPAIGNSID won't work any magic for you.  If this is a query you're going to run a lot you should consider a compound index on (CAMPAIGNSID, CONTACTSID), in that order.

Alternatively, as you don't actually use any columns from WAVECONTACTS_HISTORY you could replace the join with an IN or EXISTS sub-query.

Comment: You were right. The statistics were wrong.
I created a new index as you said containing these CAMPAIGNSID, CONTACTSID columns and now the execution is very good, from 3-5 minutes the execution takes some miliseconds.